# using if statement in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use xslt file to process xml file using if statement, but when report shows I cannos see rows, only info and total row
XML:

```
<root>
    <info org=\"101" date=\"18.11.2013\" type=\"detailReport\">
    <row № = \"1\" Name=\"Paul\" sum=\"10\">
    <row № = \"2\" Name=\"John\" sum=\"20\">
    <row № = \"3\" Name=\"Lisa\" sum=\"30\">
    <total sum=\"60\">
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
        <xsl:if test="type='detailReport'">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
                </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="total"/>
</xsl:template>
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You refer to attributes using an '@' symbol -- i.e.,

```
<xsl:if test="@type = 'detailReport'">
```

But that's not actually what you want to do here. Instead, match the `row` elements that you want to operate on, specifically:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="row[@type='detailReport']"/>          
  <xsl:apply-templates select ="total"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tryed use '@Type' but rows is stil hidden. By the way, without if statement it's ok, all rows are displayed

Comment: @MikhailSokolov Right, so did you try it the second way, where you match all the rows but qualify the match with the expression in square brackets? As I said, `xsl:if` is not what you should use here.

Comment: I convert it, but in such way how shold look 'match' ? <xsl:template match="row">